# Reagent for identification of Water Hemlock (Cicuta) or Cicutoxin?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Chemical reagents are used for macroscopic identification of some wild mushrooms. Are there similar reagents used to identify Water Hemlock (or potentially cicutoxin) as a supplement to visual identification of this incredibly poisonous plant?